# Get the improper use of a GetX has been detected. You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i got this error
If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx        or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers
and this is my code

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool expanded =false;
    return  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      body:Obx(() => PageView.builder(
        pageSnapping: true,
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 26.0),
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  AnimatedPositioned(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      bottom: expanded?150:100,

                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onPanUpdate: (details) {
                            print('object');
                            print(details.delta.dy);
                            if(details.delta.dy<0){
                                expanded=true;
                            }else if(details.delta.dy>0){
                                expanded=false;}
                          },
                          child: Image.network('https://metroparkstoledo.com/media/7672/home-rentals-700x880.jpg',height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.6))),
                ],
              ));
        },),)
    );
  }
```

i want to update bool varibale expanded using GestureDetector

Answer (score 0):

In the given code example, the

> expanded

variable is not marked as an observable variable, so the error occurs. For debugging, you can make the expanded variable observable with the obs extension provided by GetX.

```
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final RxBool expanded = false.obs; // Make expanded an observable boolean
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
    body: Obx(() => PageView.builder(
      pageSnapping: true,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 26.0),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              AnimatedPositioned(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                bottom: expanded.value ? 150 : 100, // Access the value of the observable
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onPanUpdate: (details) {
                    print('object');
                    print(details.delta.dy);
                    if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
                      expanded.value = true; // Update the value of the observable
                    } else if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
                      expanded.value = false; // Update the value of the observable
                    }
                  },
                  child: Image.network('https://metroparkstoledo.com/media/7672/home-rentals-700x880.jpg', height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    );
  }
```

}